# Oracle error while creating a trigger

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This is my SQL code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Promjenaplacanja
BEFORE UPDATE
ON Placanje
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_PlacanjeID NUMBER(10,0);
v_Starinacin NVARCHAR2(50);
v_Novinacin NVARCHAR2(50);

BEGIN

BEGIN
  SELECT :OLD.PlacanjeID ,
         :OLD.Nacin_Placanja 

    INTO v_PlacanjeID,
         v_Starinacin
    FROM DUAL ;
  SELECT :NEW.Nacin_Placanja 

    INTO v_Novinacin
    FROM DUAL ;
  INSERT INTO Auditplacanja
    ( PlacanjeID, Starinacin, Novinacin, Datum )
    VALUES ( v_PlacanjeID, v_Starinacin, v_Novinacin, SYSDATE ); 
END;
END;
```

But I got these two errors:

Error(16,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
   Error(16,19): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I don't get it, can anyone help? :\ Thanks.

Comment: Post the code in the question. Please

Comment: Do not select from dual values, insert OLD and NEW values directly into the table...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table or view does not exist. Your trigger points to a table in 2 places:

1) Creation of the trigger:  *placanje*

2) The insert statement: *auditplacanja*  (perhaps auditplacanje?).

Do both of these tables exist (in the schema you run the code)?

Comment: Auditplacanje does not exist. So I have to create table first? (It's auditplacanje, my bad)

Comment: First create the table before you can reference it in other code.